# Why not trust all http certificates

Tags: .net, security, ssl

I have written a resource manager handler for serving up resources (js/css) for several different sites in my organization. Most of the sites are internal but a few are external and use ssl. The QA/Dev sites do not have the same domain name as the certificate thus requiring me to use the callback for custom validation. I **understand** that I can do things like check my environment and return true only if not in production or check the domain name and return true if it matches my qa/dev domain. My question is not how to do it, but why? Why is it unsafe for me to accept all certificates for my resource handler? What malicious things could a user actually do?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
public static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
     return true;//Why not do this?
}
```

**Update:** Think I may need to add some clarification on what the handler does do. All requests for resources going through this handler are hashed. The handler decrypts the request and serves up the resource either via pulling it from the assembly, or by making a request for a projects own local resource. The only time the domain mismatch happens is when that local resource is requested by my handler. In retrospect I think maybe I should handle that differently, however in regards to my original questions I still do not see how a MITM attack could apply and feel like in this case it would be safe to accept all certificates, but I am not 100% why which is why I brought it up here. :)

Comment: Certificates can be forged pretty easily. Trusting all certificates would make you vulnerable to any number of attacks from an untrusted site. Also, the reason certificates _exist_ is because it is assumed that there are some people or certificates that you don't trust.

Comment: Is this server or client sided code? The code looks like client code, your description sounds like server code.

Comment: @fbfcn, that's client-side code, though.

Comment: @Bruno - [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) is server-side code.

Comment: @SilverNinja: *[...] a method to use for custom validation **by the client** of the server certificate.*

Comment: @Bruno - But in this case the client is the server, it is a handler.

Comment: Right, so as far as this connection is concerned, it's a **client**. Full stop. Forget about it being running on a server w.r.t. to a different connection. In this case, it needs to check the server certificate of what it's connecting to, as we've explained in our answers.

Comment: Just to clarify after you edit: does this make any outside connection at all (from the server)?

Comment: @fbfcn, so basically, you're worried about a certificate verifier that's never given any certificate to verify?

Comment: In this case and after the fact I realized the webrequest is not necessary as the file is local, so yes the certification verification should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify the identity of who you're exchanging secrets with, otherwise they could be an impostor.

From client to server, an active MITM attacker could use their own certificate and relay the traffic to the genuine site without you noticing. Check this question on [Security.SE: *Downside of allowing uncertified Certificates*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14089/2435).

When it comes to accepting client-certificates (from a server point of view). You'll [still exchange data secretly](https://serverfault.com/a/382782/47187) with the client, but you that won't tell you who the client is. Client-certificates are used for authentication, which you would bypass by allowing anything without extra verification (and makes this step useless).

*EDIT (You've just added that it's from the server-side point of view):*

Presumably, what you're doing is accepting any certificate and then taking the name they contain as the user's identity. The downside with that is that you're not actually doing any authentication: you're merely accepting the name the users claim to be on face value. It's a bit like accepting a piece of paper saying "My name is X" instead of checking a formal ID (e.g. passport).

Answer (score 4):

That defeats the purpose of HTTPS.

If you accept all certificates, anyone can run a man-in-the-middle attack with a self-signed certificate and it will work fine.

Comment: I do understand that but in the context of serving up css or JS I guess i am not understanding how a man-in-the middle attack would apply.

Comment: @fbfcn: An MITM can add rogue JS to arbitrarily alter the page (eg, add a keylogger)

Comment: Since this is server side, wouldn't the server have to be compromised for a MITM attack?

Comment: I agree with @SliverNinja, and I think he grasps more of what I am asking. Rogue JS really wouldn't apply since the server is not compromised only that individual has compromised them-self.

Comment: @fbfcn it's quite hard to grasp what you're trying to do since you visibly are talking about client side code. Is it running on your server, to connect to another server (in which case your server is a client in that respect)?

Comment: Correction: That defeats ONE OF the purposes of HTTPS. Even if you accept any certificate at all, the transmission between the two parties is still encrytped. So, the threat of an adversary that is able to just see your traffic (passive) being able to see your conversation is thrawted. The threat of a MITM attack is not. So, you do protect the confidentiality of the communications, you just don't have authentication of the remote party.

Answer (score 1):

You will be susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks because you are trusting any certificate that is presented to you.

*A man-in-the-middle attack can succeed only when the attacker can impersonate each endpoint to the satisfaction of the other—it is an attack on (or lack of) mutual authentication.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack